# Nextjs config file - how to export more content

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js, antd, i18next

I am trying edit nextjs config file. To use ant design and i18next.
For ant design i need this.

```
/* eslint-disable */
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css')


module.exports = 
withCss({
  webpack: (config, {
    isServer
  }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style\/css.*?/
      const origExternals = [...config.externals]
      config.externals = [
        (context, request, callback) => {
          if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback()
          if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
            origExternals[0](context, request, callback)
          } else {
            callback()
          }
        },
        ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
      ]

      config.module.rules.unshift({
        test: antStyles,
        use: 'null-loader',
      })
    }
    return config
  },
})
```

And for i18next i need

```
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    localeSubpaths: typeof process.env.LOCALE_SUBPATHS === 'string'
      ? process.env.LOCALE_SUBPATHS
      : 'none',
  },
}
```

So i combined it into:

```
/* eslint-disable */
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css')


module.exports = ({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    localeSubpaths: typeof process.env.LOCALE_SUBPATHS === 'string' ?
      process.env.LOCALE_SUBPATHS : 'none',
  }
}, withCss({
  webpack: (config, {
    isServer
  }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style\/css.*?/
      const origExternals = [...config.externals]
      config.externals = [
        (context, request, callback) => {
          if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback()
          if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
            origExternals[0](context, request, callback)
          } else {
            callback()
          }
        },
        ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
      ]

      config.module.rules.unshift({
        test: antStyles,
        use: 'null-loader',
      })
    }
    return config
  },
}))
```

But I am not sure if is it the correct way how to do it because I am still getting an error (ant design works alright and I am trying to import i18next)

```
D:\xxx\xxx\nextcms\i18n.js:4
} = require('next/config').default().publicRuntimeConfig
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'publicRuntimeConfig' of undefined
```

It can be caused by some other problem but I just need to know if I am correctly exporting those ant design with i18next.

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your entire export using `withCss()`.

Try this instead:

```
/* eslint-disable */
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css')


module.exports = withCss({
  publicRuntimeConfig: {

   // ...

  },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {

    // ...

    return config
  },
})
```